# Writing and running R functions

Tags: r, function, user-defined-functions

I am having problem in running functions in R.
Whenever I want to run them I always get the message that the function/object is not available. though I saved it in the working directory.
For it to run, I have to paste it in the R window. Any idea on what I am missing highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `source` function to read the file.

If you do this a lot, I recommend the package `devtools`, or RStudio.  Or both.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  That is not a function (not that it makes any difference, files can contain more than just functions).

Comment: Sorry, I created a function just as normal f<-function(x=4){....} and saved it in my setwd. However when I try to call it f() or f(4) the tells me that the object is not available. but when I paste all the function on the R window and call it then it works.

Comment: Saving the function definition as a file does not evaluate (define) it. As Matthew says, you need to use `source` to evaluate the function and bring it into the namespace. When you paste the function into the REPL, that's what's happening. In other words, if you save the function in a file `my-function.R`, you can then have R evaluate it by `source("./my-function.R")`.

Answer (score 0):

So as exposed above, there are several steps to follow. It won't work if one of them is missing :-)

1) Set your source folder

```
setwd("///.../admin/Documents")
```

2) Create your function and save it:

```
fun = function(...){
your function
}

dump("fun", file = "Code_fun.R")
```

3) Call your function

```
source("Code_fun.R")
```

Then you can go ahead

```
fun(3) = ...
```